# Count all results at one

Tags: postgresql

I have queries with `UNION ALL` it looks like this, but then going same queries but with other conditionals

```
select count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%') as "Summary",
       count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%' and completed is true) as "Summary Completed",
       'Child Seat' "Type of car-class/seat"
from archived_order 
where created_user_login like 'exchangeAgent@shara' 
  and created between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2568%'),
       count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2568%' and completed is true),
       'Child seat economy 1-3'
from archived_order 
where created_user_login not like 'exchangeAgent@shara' 
  and data like '%"cci":4%' 
  and created between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2568%') as a,
       count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2568%' and completed is true),
       'Child seat standart 1-3'
from archived_order 
where created_user_login not like 'exchangeAgent@shara' 
  and data like '%"cci":1%' 
  and created between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date;
```

I've tried to count by doing `as` and tried to select it with count, but it seems not working. I don't know exactly how to count for 2 columns all entries like this `count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2568%')`

and all entries like this `count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2568%' and completed is true)`

My goal is to get 2 numbers where will be a sum of all the values from each count.

```
 Summary | Summary Completed | Type of car-class/seat
---------+-------------------+-------------------------
   12899 |             10653 |
      97 |                94 | Child seat standart 1-3
      18 |                12 | Child seat economy 1-3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CTE` on which you can get the sums:

```
with cte as (
select count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%') as "Summary",
       count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%' and completed is true) as "Summary Completed",
       'Child Seat' "Type of car-class/seat"
from archived_order 
where created_user_login like 'exchangeAgent@shara' 
  and created between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2568%'),
       count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2568%' and completed is true),
       'Child seat economy 1-3'
from archived_order 
where created_user_login not like 'exchangeAgent@shara' 
  and data like '%"cci":4%' 
  and created between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2568%') as a,
       count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2568%' and completed is true),
       'Child seat standart 1-3'
from archived_order 
where created_user_login not like 'exchangeAgent@shara' 
  and data like '%"cci":1%' 
  and created between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date
)
select sum("Summary") "Summary", sum("Summary Completed") "Summary Completed", null
from cte
union all
select * from cte
```

Comment: created_user_login like should be only on CHILD_SEAT, and should be not like for `pmi` for every pmi conditional. How can i do this?

Comment: You are right, i missed the *not*. Let me check it.

Comment: Check my edited answer and also note that you can use `=` instead of `like` here: `created_user_login like 'exchangeAgent@shara'` since you are only checking for equality and `<>` for inequality.

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much. I've checked and made some minor edits already for other conditionals

Comment: I've tried with all my conditionals your last query, but it gave me all orders where user login like and not like. And below this i've got than results for the conditionals. But it way more less than the result above

Comment: Your 1st condition is `created_user_login like 'exchangeAgent@shara'`, so it is not related to the other 2, right?

Comment: Yeah. But when it comes to `count(id) as "Summary"` it giving me all orders which has been made yesterday. And below this i'm getting numbers which i'm already know from other queries.

Comment: But it's going to be good, if you can do this like this, i will be able to short it out more)

Comment: So where is the problem? Only in the results of the 1st condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204877/discussion-between-lotarc-and-forpas).